# Wrong gopath when debugging project in VS Code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, delve, gopath

From one day to the next I can't manage to debug a project where everything worked perfectly before.
I'm sure I haven't changed anything about the project or its settings during this time. All I did was work on another project in the same **IDE (VS Code)**.

### The actual error in VS Code:

```
dbInteraction.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" in any of:
C:\Go\src\github.com\go-sql-driver\mysql (from $GOROOT)
c:\Users\Mani\Documents\Programmier Projekte\PRJCTNAME\src\github.com\go-sql-driver\mysql (from $GOPATH)
main.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/mux" in any of:
C:\Go\src\github.com\gorilla\mux (from $GOROOT)
c:\Users\Mani\Documents\Programmier Projekte\PRJCTNAME\src\github.com\gorilla\mux (from $GOPATH)
exit status 1
Process exiting with code: 1
```

### Checking the environment variables:

```
C:\Users\Mani>echo %GOPATH%
C:\Users\Mani\go

C:\Users\Mani>echo %GOROOT%
C:\Go\
```

As you can see, my environment variables are set as desired and the $GOPATH in the debug output does not match this path; in contract it is the actual path of my go sources for this project.

When i build the project over the command line with `go build` (in the project directory) it works perfectly. That gives me the suspicion that VS Code is responsible for the problem.

**The user settings and workspace settings in VS Code are both empty. Also empty is the project specific VS-Code `settings.go` and the `launch.go` has not changed from the default.**

**EDIT 1:** If i remember correctly, i think I switched from `VS Code 32bit` to `VS Code 64bit` in between.

**EDIT 2:** After setting the env parameter in the launch.json I am able to debug the program again but now i ***do not get any output in the debug console.***

Answer (score -1):

If you're using the vscode-go extension, try changing the `go.gopath` setting as described on [the Microsoft vscode-go wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/GOPATH-in-the-VS-Code-Go-extension):

> Setting `go.gopath` in User settings overrides the GOPATH that was derived from the above logic. Setting `go.gopath` in Workspace settings overrides the one from User settings. You can set multiple folders as GOPATH in this setting. Note that they should be `;` separated in Windows and `:` separated otherwise.

I initially had problems with Visual Studio Code recognising my gopath, and this fixed it.

Comment: already followed everything in this list before with no change at all, so i've redone that settings

Comment: Are you using the dlv debugger?

Comment: This information *belongs* in an answer, you just need to add a *summary* of the information into your answer itself, so it's not all buried behind that link and subject to becoming lost when the link inevitably rots. We require that all answers here be self-contained. That either needs to be a summary in your own words, or a quotation of the relevant portions, with appropriate [referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). I edited that into your answer for you this time. Please use this as a model for future answers!

Comment: My apologies, thank you very much for the advice. I will be sure to keep this in mind in the future!

Comment: @fanduin If you mean the Delve debugger, than yes, i use it